# CGI post handling differences on Hiawatha and Apache

Tags: apache, post, cgi, common-lisp, hiawatha

I'm trying to set up a light development environment to allow straight CGI in Common Lisp, and I'd like to use Hiawatha instead of the much larger Apache.  I have code that works for both GET and POST in Apache, but only GET in Hiawatha; is there a difference in the way Apache and Hiawatha handle POST?

Answer (score 0):

The [CGI specification](http://hoohoo.ncsa.uiuc.edu/cgi/interface.html) only specifies that POST data should be sent to a CGI script using the program's `STDIN`, as opposed to GET which is sent in the environment variable `QUERY_STRING`.

Comment: I must have been unclear; I meant that my code worked for both GET and POST in Apache, but only GET in Hiawatha.  I'll edit.